# HTML PHP get select value in same page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a question about HTML select form.

I have 5 select forms something like following picture.
[image: pic 1]

You have to select from the first select form, and then the second select form will display the lists by value select from the previous select form.

The lists are getting from MYSQL.

How should I perform above function?

Comment: Use AJAX.  When the first changes you'll need to make an AJAX call to a PHP page to get the list for the second, etc.

Comment: There are probably 100 answers to this on this site alone. Do some basic research.

Comment: @PatrickQ maybe 1000

Comment: Thanks to all of you! Maybe I have to try more basic search. It's my first time to do the web programming. It seems like to be a big challenge for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by wrapping a jQuery.ajax call inside of a .change() listener on each of the drop downs.

The ajax call would hit a PHP file that would execute the MySQL queries and return the HTML to generate the list on the next dropdown.

I would start here.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

https://api.jquery.com/change/

This should get you started, If you need help along the way just post a comment or edit your question above to provide more information and I would be happy to help.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!